# Pointer events work only on part of a div

Tags: c#, blazor

I have a razor component defined liked this:
File `WindowContainer.razor`

```html
<div @onpointermove="OnMouseMove"
     @onpointerdown="OnMouseDown"
     @onpointerup="OnMouseUp"
     @onpointerout="OnMouseUp"
     style="min-width: @Width; max-width: @Width; min-height: @Height; max-height: @Height">
        @ChildContent
</div>
```

File `WindowContainer.cs`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

namespace DiceOS.View.Components.Windows
{
    public partial class WindowContainer
    {
        [Parameter] public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public string Height { get; set; }
        [Parameter] public string Width { get; set; }

        private void OnMouseMove(PointerEventArgs args)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Moving");
        }

        private void OnMouseDown()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Down");
        }

        private void OnMouseUp()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Up");
        }
    }
}
```

And use it on a page

```html
    <WindowContainer Width='"500px"' Height='"500px"'>
        Content Text
    </WindowContainer>
```

And even though div is 500px x 500px I see debug messages only when hovering over area occupied by "Content Text". How to make events fire for whole div's area?

Comment: Inline `style` elements don't use quotes around values.  Inspect the page, and I think you'll see that the html isn't well-formed.  Try `<WindowContainer Width="500px" Height="500px">` without the extra quotes.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973
You are right, it was so simple that I am ashamed I even posted this question.

Comment: I recently deleted the @page directive off from one of the EF scaffolded pages because I didn't think pre-Blazor stuff used it.  Then I spent literally 6 hours trying to find the problem when my Login page wouldn't load.  Headslap!  Short version: `We're all in the same boat.`